# Powershell: If else help: user is member of group function

Tags: powershell, windows-7

My goal is to run a powershell script that will see if the current user is a member of a group. If the user is a member then it will change the content of a file. If not, it just exits. I just ran it and the changes on my files were not made.

I know that individually these 2 separate scripts work as advertised. I need help determining why when I combine them its not giving me the desired result since there are no error messages:

```
 Import-Module ActiveDirectory

 $group = "The Beatles"
 $members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Recursive | Select -ExpandProperty Name

if($members -contains $ENV:USERNAME)
{
    $File = "\\server\folder\$($Env:USERNAME)\File.reg"
    $Content = Get-Content -Path $File | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $_ -replace 'peter best',$ENV:USERNAME
    } 
    Set-Content -Path $File -Value $Content  
}
else
{
    Exit
}
```

I replaced the contents of the if bracket with: Write-Host "WINNER WINNER!" and it still didn't do anything. But if I replace the if with a for and eliminate the else portion it works spits out "WINNER WINNER!". My guess is that my syntax or understanding on how to execute the code inside the If curly brackets is the culprit.

How do I get the desired result?

I appreciate the input.

Thanks,

Victor

Comment: Have you ensured that `$members` contains objects of the same form as `$ENV:USERNAME`? There may be some translation required.

Answer (score 2):

The Active Directory `Name` attribute value is unlikely to be the same as the username (ie. your might be "Victor Antifries" but your username might be "v.antifries" or "victor01").

You'd want to grab the `SAMAccountName` property instead:

```
$members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Recursive | Select -ExpandProperty SAMAccountName
```

Comment: Thank you for the input. I made the suggested change. Still same as before.

Comment: @VictorAntifries easy way to inspect the `$members` values: `$members |%{'"{0}"' -f $_}` - you should see each value enclosed in double quotes (which makes it easier to spot trailing whitepace)

Comment: Thank You, Mathias. I don't know what that means or how to make it work, but I know it is of great value.

Comment: @VictorAntifries Just replace the whole `if/else` block with `$members |%{'"{0}"' -f $_}`, run the script again and then see what is written to the screen. Should give you an indication of why it's not working

Comment: Its still not editing the reg file but I wanted to say thanks for your follow-up comment. I was able to use it.